# How to compute jaccard similarity from a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, machine-learning, similarity

I have a dataframe as follows: the shape of the frame is (1510, 1399). The columns represent products, the rows represent values (0 or 1) assigned by a user for a given product. How can I can compute `jaccard_similarity_score`s?

[image]

I created a placeholder dataframe listing product vs. product

```py
data_ibs = pd.DataFrame(index=data_g.columns,columns=data_g.columns)
```

I am not sure how to iterate though data_ibs to compute similarities.

```py
for i in range(0,len(data_ibs.columns)) :
    # Loop through the columns for each column
    for j in range(0,len(data_ibs.columns)) :
        .........
```

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Use `pairwise_distances` to calculate the distance and subtract that distance from 1 to find the similarity score:

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import pairwise_distances
1 - pairwise_distances(df.T.to_numpy(), metric='jaccard')
```

---

Explanation:

In newer versions of scikit learn, the definition of `jaccard_score` is similar to the Jaccard similarity coefficient definition in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index):

[image]

where

- M<sub>11</sub> represents the total number of attributes where A and B both have a value of 1.
- M<sub>01</sub> represents the total number of attributes where the attribute of A is 0 and the attribute of B is 1.
- M<sub>10</sub> represents the total number of attributes where the attribute of A is 1 and the attribute of B is 0.
- M<sub>00</sub> represents the total number of attributes where A and B both have a value of 0.

Let's create a sample dataset to see if the results match:

```
from pandas import DataFrame, crosstab
from numpy.random import default_rng
rng = default_rng(0)

# Create a dataframe of 40 rows and 5 columns (named A, B, C, D, E)
# Each cell in the DataFrame is either 0 or 1 with 50% probability
df = DataFrame(rng.binomial(1, 0.5, size=(40, 5)), columns=list('ABCDE'))
```

This yields the following crosstab for columns A and B:

| A/B | 0 | 1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 10 | 7 |
| 1 | 14 | 9 |

Based on the definition, the Jaccard similarity score is:

```
M00 = (df['A'].eq(0) & df['B'].eq(0)).sum()  # 10
M01 = (df['A'].eq(0) & df['B'].eq(1)).sum()  # 7
M10 = (df['A'].eq(1) & df['B'].eq(0)).sum()  # 14
M11 = (df['A'].eq(1) & df['B'].eq(1)).sum()  # 9


print(M11 / (M01 + M10 + M11))  # 0.3
```

This is what you would get with `jaccard_score`:

```
from sklearn.metrics import jaccard_score
print(jaccard_score(df['A'], df['B']))  # 0.3
```

The problem with the `jaccard_score` function is that it is not vectorized. You'll have to loop over all columns to calculate the similarity score for each corresponding column. In order to avoid that, you can use the vectorized distance version. However, since it is "distance" but not "similarity", you'll need to subtract that value from 1:

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import pairwise_distances
print(1 - pairwise_distances(df.T.to_numpy(), metric='jaccard'))

# [[1.         0.3        0.45714286 0.34285714 0.46666667]
#  [0.3        1.         0.29411765 0.33333333 0.23333333]
#  [0.45714286 0.29411765 1.         0.40540541 0.44117647]
#  [0.34285714 0.33333333 0.40540541 1.         0.36363636]
#  [0.46666667 0.23333333 0.44117647 0.36363636 1.        ]]
```

Optionally, you can convert it back to a DataFrame:

```
jac_sim = 1 - pairwise_distances(df.T.to_numpy(), metric='jaccard')
jac_sim_df = DataFrame(
    1 - pairwise_distances(df.T.to_numpy(), metric='jaccard'), 
    index=df.columns, columns=df.columns,
)

#           A         B         C         D         E
#  A  1.000000  0.300000  0.457143  0.342857  0.466667
#  B  0.300000  1.000000  0.294118  0.333333  0.233333
#  C  0.457143  0.294118  1.000000  0.405405  0.441176
#  D  0.342857  0.333333  0.405405  1.000000  0.363636
#  E  0.466667  0.233333  0.441176  0.363636  1.000000
```

Note: In the previous version of this answer, the calculations used the hamming metric with `pairwise_distances` because in earlier versions of scikit-learn, `jaccard_score` was calculated similar to the accuracy score (i.e. (M<sub>00</sub> + M<sub>11</sub>) / (M<sub>00</sub> + M<sub>01</sub> + M<sub>10</sub> + M<sub>11</sub>)). That is no longer the case so the answer was updated to use the `jaccard` metric instead of `hamming`.

Comment: Actually I think I can get the Jaccard distance by 1 minus Jaccard similarity.

Comment: Of course, based on the definition those may change. What I meant was sklearn's jaccard_similarity_score is not equal to 1 - sklearn's jaccard distance. But it is equal to 1 - sklearn's hamming distance. Wikipedia's definition, for example, is different than sklearn's.

Comment: I can't believe this does not have more upvotes. Excellent work. Thanks

Comment: Hi @ayhan is it possible to remove the half of the result diagonally? due to duplication values in the result? 

Thanks

Comment: Hi @ayhan to zero

Comment: @ayhan how to do the same when you have 1 million rows in Dask dataframe

Comment: In my case I do not obtain the same result…

Comment: Same as carlos: `print(jaccard_score(df['A'], df['B']))` yields 0.24

Comment: On the other hand `1-pairwise_distances(df.T.values, metric = "jaccard")` yields the correct result

Answer (score 0):

Jaccard similarity scores can also be calculated using [`scipy.spatial.distance.pdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html). One of its metrics is `'jaccard'` which computes jaccard dissimilarity (so that the score has to be subtracted from 1 to get jaccard similarity). It returns a 1D array where each value corresponds to the jaccard similarity between two columns.

One could construct a Series from the scores by constructing a MultiIndex.

```py
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist
jaccard_similarity = pd.Series(1 - pdist(df.values.T, metric='jaccard'), index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(c1, c2) for i, c1 in enumerate(df) for c2 in df.columns[i+1:]]))
```

Using [ayhan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37004489/19123103)'s setup, it produces the following:

```py
A  B    0.300000
   C    0.457143
   D    0.342857
   E    0.466667
B  C    0.294118
   D    0.333333
   E    0.233333
C  D    0.405405
   E    0.441176
D  E    0.363636
dtype: float64
```

If a matrix is desired, it can be constructed from `pdist` as well. Just construct an empty matrix and fill the off-diagonals by these values (and the diagonal by 1).

```py
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist

def jaccard_similarity_matrix(df):
    
    n = df.shape[1]
    scores = 1 - pdist(np.array(df).T, metric='jaccard')
    result = np.zeros((n,n))
    result[np.triu_indices(n, k=1)] = scores
    result += result.T
    np.fill_diagonal(result, 1)
    return pd.DataFrame(result, index=df.columns, columns=df.columns)

jaccard_similarity = jaccard_similarity_matrix(df)
```

[image: result]

---

In fact, by using the [source code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.10.1/scipy/spatial/distance.py#L1952-L2255) of `pdist`, an entirely custom function that only uses numpy and basic python may be written as well.

```py
def jaccard_matrix(df):

    def jaccard(x, y):
        nonzero = (x != 0) | (y != 0)
        a = ((x != y) & nonzero).sum()
        b = nonzero.sum()
        return 1 - a / b if b != 0 else 1
    
    arr = df.values
    n = arr.shape[1]
    scores = [jaccard(arr[:, i], arr[:, j]) for i in range(n-1) for j in range(i+1, n)]
    result = np.zeros((n, n))
    result[np.triu_indices(n, k=1)] = scores
    result += result.T
    np.fill_diagonal(result, 1)
    return pd.DataFrame(result, index=df.columns, columns=df.columns)
```

All of these functions return the same output which can be verified as follows:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.default_rng().binomial(1, 0.5, size=(100, 10))).add_prefix('col')
x = pd.DataFrame(1 - pairwise_distances(df.values.T.astype(bool), metric='jaccard'), index=df.columns, columns=df.columns)
y = jaccard_similarity_matrix(df)
z = jaccard_matrix(df)

np.allclose(x, y) and np.allclose(y, z)    # True
```