# Computing Jaccard Similarity between DataFrame Columns with Different Lengths

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, scikit-learn

I have a dataframe with user_ids as columns and the ids of the movies they've liked as row values. Here's a snippet:

```
   15       30       50        93       100     113      1008    1028    
0  3346.0  42779.0   1816.0  191319.0    138.0   183.0    171.0   283.0   
1  1543.0      NaN    169.0    5319.0  34899.0   188.0  42782.0  1183.0   
2  5942.0      NaN  30438.0  195514.0    169.0   172.0    187.0  5329.0   
3  3249.0      NaN  32361.0     225.0     87.0   547.0   6710.0   283.0   
4   794.0      NaN    187.0  195734.0   6297.0  8423.0   1289.0   222.0
```

I'm trying to calculate the Jaccard Similarity between each column (i.e. between each user using the movies they've liked). Python gives the following error when I try to use the jaccard_similarity_score found in sklearn:

```
ValueError: continuous is not supported
```

Ideally, as a result, I would like to get a matrix with rows and columns of user_id's and the values as the similarity scores for each.

How can I go about computing the jaccard similarities between these columns? I've tried to use a list of dictionaries with keys as user Ids and values as lists of movies, but it takes forever to compute.

Comment: Possible dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37003272/how-to-compute-jaccard-similarity-from-a-pandas-dataframe

Comment: My columns have unequal lengths and I shouldn't do pairwise since equal movie_id's don't necessarily have equal indexes (i.e. I shouldn't compare column_1[i] and column_2[i]. i should instead do set(column[1]) vs set(column[2]))

Comment: can you post your desired data set?

Comment: do you mean the desired result?

Comment: yes, post your desired result in the question

Comment: the desired result is now included

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `sklearn.metrics.jaccard_similarity_score` expects two input vectors of equal length you could try something like the following, partially addapted from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37003272/how-to-compute-jaccard-similarity-from-a-pandas-dataframe) similar question.

```
import itertools
import pandas as pd

# Method to compute Jaccard similarity index between two sets
def compute_jaccard(user1_vals, user2_vals):
    intersection = user1_vals.intersection(user2_vals)
    union = user1_vals.union(user2_vals)
    jaccard = len(intersection)/float(len(union))
    return jaccard

# Small test dataframe
users = ['user1', 'user2', 'user3']
df = pd.DataFrame( 
    np.transpose(np.array([[1,2,3],[3,np.NAN,7], [np.NAN, np.NAN,3]])), 
    columns=users)
sim_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=users, index=users)

# Iterate through columns and compute metric
for col_pair in itertools.combinations(df.columns, 2):
    u1= col_pair[0]
    u2 = col_pair[1]
    sim_df.loc[col_pair] = compute_jaccard(set(df[u1].dropna()), set(df[u2].dropna()))


print sim_df
```

This returns the following (upper triangular) half of the similarity matrix where the diagonal would of course be all ones.

```
        user1  user2     user3
user1   NaN    0.25      0.333333
user2   NaN    NaN       0.5
user3   NaN    NaN       NaN
```